# Programmatically check for Asset updates

Tags: unity-game-engine

I couldn't find any way to programmatically fetch the current version of an Asset (from the Asset Store) to match it against the currently installed one.

Also, I didn't find an Asset Store API (Except for the affiliate program https://unity3d.com/affiliates but this seems not be designed for that. Am I wrong?)

And while I could probably fetch the HTTP page and parse, that's monkey patching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to programmatically check for outdated assets in the `Package Manager` in `Unity 2021`.

## Example

Here's a class which allows you to check for outdated asset packages. After importing the script, go to `Custom` menu and click on one of the 3 newly created menu items. Shortly after that, the editor should inform you through the console window if there are any outdated assets.

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.PackageManager.Requests;
using UnityEditor.PackageManager;

public static class AssetVersionChecker
{
    private static ListRequest Request;
    private static Action actionToHandle;

    [MenuItem("Custom/Check Asset Packages For Updates (Latest)")]
    private static void CheckPackagesForLatestUpdates() => Handle(
        "Latest",
        () => PrintOutdatedPackages(GetOutdatedLatestPackages()));

    [MenuItem("Custom/Check Asset Packages For Updates (Latest Compatible)")]
    private static void CheckPackagesForLatestCompatibleUpdates() => Handle(
        "Latest Compatible",
        () => PrintOutdatedPackages(GetOutdatedLatestCompatiblePackages()));

    [MenuItem("Custom/Check Asset Packages For Updates (Verified)")]
    private static void CheckPackagesForVerifiedUpdates() => Handle(
        "Verified",
        () => PrintOutdatedPackages(GetOutdatedVerifiedPackages()));
    
    private static void Handle(string label, Action action)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Checking for updates ({label})...");

        // Listing packages installed in the project
        Request = Client.List();
        actionToHandle = action;

        EditorApplication.update += OnEditorApplicationUpdate;
    }

    private static void OnEditorApplicationUpdate()
    {
        if (Request.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (Request.Status == StatusCode.Success)
                actionToHandle();
            else if (Request.Status >= StatusCode.Failure)
                Debug.Log(Request.Error.message);

            EditorApplication.update -= OnEditorApplicationUpdate;
        }
    }

    private static void PrintOutdatedPackages(IEnumerable<PrintablePackageInfo> packages)
    {
        if (packages.Count() == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("All packages are up to date!");
            return;
        }

        foreach (var package in packages)
        {
            Debug.Log(
                $"{package.Name} out of date! " +
                $"Current: {package.CurrentVersion}, " +
                $"Latest: {package.LatestVersion}");
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PrintablePackageInfo> GetOutdatedLatestPackages() => Request
        .Result
        .Where(x => x.version != x.versions.latest)
        .Select(x => new PrintablePackageInfo(x.name, x.version, x.versions.latest));

    private static IEnumerable<PrintablePackageInfo> GetOutdatedLatestCompatiblePackages() => Request
        .Result
        .Where(x => x.version != x.versions.latestCompatible)
        .Select(x => new PrintablePackageInfo(x.name, x.version, x.versions.latestCompatible));

    private static IEnumerable<PrintablePackageInfo> GetOutdatedVerifiedPackages() => Request
        .Result
        .Where(x => x.versions.verified != string.Empty)
        .Where(x => x.version != x.versions.verified)
        .Select(x => new PrintablePackageInfo(x.name, x.version, x.versions.verified));

    struct PrintablePackageInfo
    {
        public readonly string Name;
        public readonly string CurrentVersion;
        public readonly string LatestVersion;

        public PrintablePackageInfo(string name, string currentVersion, string latestVersion)
        {
            Name = name;
            CurrentVersion = currentVersion;
            LatestVersion = latestVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

## References

Here's a Unity Docs page that helped me with writing this solution:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-api.html